# Show data in tooltip but not on chart

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have three datasets where data is object type and each axis data is parsed by object key.
I want to hide `no_transp` dataset related line from chart and legend, but still show it in tooltip.

**Datasets**

```
const chartData = {
    labels: data.map(item => item.period),
    datasets: [
        {
            data,
            backgroundColor: '#1F77B4',
            borderColor: '#1F77B4',
            label: i18n.purchasePrice,
            parsing: { yAxisKey: 'price_po', xAxisKey: 'period' },
        },
        {
            data,
            backgroundColor: '#1DCF35',
            borderColor: '#1DCF35',
            label: i18n.sellPrice,
            parsing: { yAxisKey: 'price_so', xAxisKey: 'period' },
        },
        {
            data,
            label: i18n.transportationsNo,
            backgroundColor: '#FAA46A',
            borderColor: '#FAA46A',
            showLine: false,
            pointStyle: false,
            parsing: { yAxisKey: 'no_transp', xAxisKey: 'period' },
            yAxisID: 'y2',
        },
    ],
};
```

Problem is that setting hidden property on dataset will prevent data from appearing in tooltip. Solution is to pass callback to tooltip plugin and access all required data from context, but I have no control on tooltip point styling as callback function for label is called for each dataset (purchase price, sell price) and return type of callback is string  or string[]  (so I can not do anything to label styling). Other problem callback is per label (per dataset that is not hidden), but I can skip rendering other labels for other datasets and render all info for first label (and as mentioned before it will have blue point for label and list of three strings with data when I want result as per image).

[image: Transportation lines and points hidden, data still affects Y axis]

Currently I came up with solution to set `showLine: false`, `pointStyle: false` and `yAxisID: 'y2'` so line and points are hidden from chart and line has own axis. Also I need to pass filer function to legend plugin labels to hide it from legend

```
legend: {
    labels: {
        filter: legendItem => legendItem.text !== i18n.transportationsNo,
    },
},
```

And set `display: false` on y2 axis to hide axis itself.

```
scales: {
    y2: {
        display: false,
    },
},
```

[image]

Is there any other solution to set `hidden: true` on dataset (or other solution) and still show data in tooltip (respecting all colors set in dataset) without creating fancy workarounds or external html tooltip.

Comment: I think you could use a specific API to hide a dataset: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#setdatasetvisibility-datasetindex-visibility

Comment: @user2057925, this will hide data from dataset, so it won't be visible in tooltip as well.

Comment: Ah ok, you want to see it even if hidden.

Comment: I think you could implement a custom interaction for tooltip

Comment: @user2057925 as stated in problem I want to avoid custom implementation. When dataset is hidden I need custom implementation for tooltip anyway. So bests solution would be to render data in tooltip for hidden datasets as well, but as far as I know API for tooltip does not have this option, so I need external HTML anyway (as in build functions only allows to return string or string array, but not html elements or ReactNode in my case).

Comment: Without any customization, I don't think this is doable, at least for my knowledge.

Comment: Here a codepen where using a custom interaction you can have tooltip items even if the dataset is hidden: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/VwEKGam. External tooltip is receiving the tooltip model where these items are avaialble for your HTML